# Add a legend for an animation (of Artists) in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have made an animation from a set of images like this (10 snapshots):[image]

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Circle
import time

infile = open ('out.txt')

frame_counter = 0

N_p = 100
N_step = 10
N_line = N_p*N_step

for s in xrange(N_step):
        x, y = [], []
        for i in xrange(N_p):
                data = infile.readline()
                raw = data.split()
                x.append(float(raw[0]))
                y.append(float(raw[1]))

        xnp = np.array(x)
        ynp = np.array(y)

        fig = plt.figure(0)
        ax = fig.add_subplot(111, aspect='equal')
        for x, y in zip(xnp, ynp):

                cir = Circle(xy = (x, y), radius = 1)
                cir.set_facecolor('red')
                ax.add_artist(cir)
                cir.set_clip_box(ax.bbox)

                ax.set_xlim(-10, 150)
                ax.set_ylim(-10, 150)
        fig.savefig("step.%04d.png" % frame_counter)
        ax.remove()
        frame_counter +=1
```

Now I want to add a legend to each image showing the time step.
For doing this I must set legends to each of these 10 images. The problem is that I have tested different things like **ax.set_label** , **cir.set_label**, ...
and I get errors like this:

```
 UserWarning: No labelled objects found. Use label='...' kwarg on individual plots
```

According to this error I must add label to my individual plots, but since this is a plot of Artists, I don't know how I can do this.

Comment: Why do you need a legend here when there is only one type of dot being shown?

Comment: I would like to show time in the animation.

Comment: Let me refine: Why do you need a legend to show time in the animation when there is only one type of dot being shown?

Comment: I am learning matplotlib by myself, and in every trial plot I would like to add different things, so that later I can use these example file. I just find an example of what I like to do, the pendulum animation in https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2012/08/18/matplotlib-animation-tutorial/

Comment: Anyways, if the answer below solves the issue, you should [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it, if not, you should refine your question.

Comment: In this example the second approach of your response has been used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If for whatever reason you need a [legend](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.legend), you can show your Circle as the handle and use some text as the label.

```
ax.legend(handles=[cir], labels=["{}".format(frame_counter)])
```

If you don't really need a legend, you can just use some [text](http://matplotlib.org/users/text_intro.html) to place inside the axes.

```
ax.text(.8,.8, "{}".format(frame_counter), transform=ax.transAxes)
```