# How to draw animated legend for subplots?

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib, legend, subplot

I would like to draw animated subplots with ArtistAnimation. Unfortunately, I cannot figure out how to have an animated legend. I tried out different methods I found on StackOverflow. If I manage to get a legend it is not animated, but just the legends of all animation steps together.

My code looks like this:

```
import numpy as np
import pylab as pl
import matplotlib.animation as anim

fig, (ax1, ax2, ax3) = pl.subplots(1,3,figsize=(11,4))
ims   = []
im1   = ['im11','im12','im13']
im2   = ['im21','im22','im23']
x = np.arange(0,2*np.pi,0.1)

n=50
for i in range(n):
    for sp in (1,2,3):
        pl.subplot(1,3,sp)

        y1 = np.sin(sp*x + i*np.pi/n)
        y2 = np.cos(sp*x + i*np.pi/n)

        im1[sp-1], = pl.plot(x,y1)
        im2[sp-1], = pl.plot(x,y2)

        pl.xlim([0,2*np.pi])
        pl.ylim([-1,1])

        lab = 'i='+str(i)+', sp='+str(sp)
        im1[sp-1].set_label([lab])
        pl.legend(loc=2, prop={'size': 6}).draw_frame(False)

    ims.append([ im1[0],im1[1],im1[2], im2[0],im2[1],im2[2] ])

ani = anim.ArtistAnimation(fig,ims,blit=True)
pl.show()
```

[image: This is how the result looks like]

I thought this code would be equivalent to the method used here [How to add legend/label in python animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35677980/how-to-add-legend-label-in-python-animation) but obviously I am missing something.

I also tried to set the labels as suggested in [Add a legend for an animation (of Artists) in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41191273/add-a-legend-for-an-animation-of-artists-in-matplotlib?rq=1) but I do not really understand how to use it for my case. Like this

```
im2[sp-1].legend(handles='-', labels=[lab])
```

I get an `AttributeError: 'Line2D' object has no attribute 'legend'`.

**[EDIT]:** I did not state it clearly: I would like to have a legend for both lines in the plots.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do not know what exactly the legend should look like, but I'd imaginge you simply want to let it display the current value of the one line from the current frame. You'd therefore better update the data of the line, instead of plotting 150 new plots.

```
import numpy as np
import pylab as plt
import matplotlib.animation as anim

fig, axes = plt.subplots(1,3,figsize=(8,3))
ims   = []
im1   = [ax.plot([],[], label="label")[0] for ax in axes]
im2   = [ax.plot([],[], label="label")[0] for ax in axes]
x = np.arange(0,2*np.pi,0.1)

legs = [ax.legend(loc=2, prop={'size': 6})  for ax in axes]

for ax in axes:
    ax.set_xlim([0,2*np.pi])
    ax.set_ylim([-1,1])
plt.tight_layout()
n=50
def update(i):
    for sp in range(3):
        y1 = np.sin((sp+1)*x + (i)*np.pi/n)
        y2 = np.cos((sp+1)*x + (i)*np.pi/n)

        im1[sp].set_data(x,y1)
        im2[sp].set_data(x,y2)

        lab = 'i='+str(i)+', sp='+str(sp+1)
        legs[sp].texts[0].set_text(lab)
        legs[sp].texts[1].set_text(lab)

    return im1 + im2 +legs 

ani = anim.FuncAnimation(fig,update, frames=n,blit=True)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: It seems that my minimal example was a bit too minimal. :)
I would like a legend for both lines. I can add `legs2` and manually shift it to the good position, but it is not automatically associated with the second (here: orange) data.

Until now, I preferred the loop-version (instead of using `def`) because, in reality, I am working with data with 30000 `i`s and have to skip most of them. Is there a way to include something like a `continue` or `break` condition in the `update(i)`?

Comment: Calling the `update` function with `i` given by `frames=something` is the same as a loop `for i in something`. Hence I do not see any problem with that. But of course you can also do a ArtistAnimation from the code above, just also add the legend to the list artists. I updated the answer with two legend entries.

Comment: I did not manage to get it working with ArtistAnimation, but using `frames=n` with comprehensive lists did the job. Thanks!